# My nav bar wont open up and let me access my site

Tags: html, css, nav

[the first picture is my html code for the navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBdGd.jpg)

[The second picture is for my css code for navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkpKV.jpg)

Comment: If you can add your code instead of the screen schot of it someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Please add a code example directly to the question rather than posting screenshots of them to create [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It makes it practically impossible to answer a question when its posted as screenshots which cannot be executed.